# Does setting the integrity priority of the dll on the development machine persist on the install-build

Tags: c++, installshield, integrity

I use IShellLink to get the target path of a shortcut. Most of the time it is good, but I am missing some of the files once in a while. I read somewhere that the Integrity Priority could be an issue. See Integrity Priority here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx
My question is - if I change the integrity priority of all the dll on my development machine, then build an install build with these dll's, and then move the install-build to another machine and install the program there; will the medium integrity priority I set persist on the new machine. Or I have to write a script to change the integrity priority after I install the program.
I am hoping I dont need to do anything after the install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the IShellLink functionality very well so I'll try to address this from the Windows Installer point of view. ( Assuming that by referencing the installshield tag that you are using MSI. )

MSI uses the [Shortcut table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and if on Win7/Server2008R2 the [ShortcutProperty Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This article [Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a section that says:

> In the System.AppUserModel.ID property of the application's shortcut
>   file. A shortcut (as an IShellLink, CLSID_ShellLink, or a .lnk file)
>   supports properties through IPropertyStore and other property-setting
>   mechanisms used throughout the Shell. This allows the taskbar to
>   identify the proper shortcut to pin and ensures that windows belonging
>   to the process are appropriately associated with that taskbar button. 
>   Note  The System.AppUserModel.ID property should be applied to a
>   shortcut when that shortcut is created. When using the Microsoft
>   Windows Installer (MSI) to install the application, the
>   MsiShortcutProperty table allows the AppUserModelID to be applied to
>   the shortcut when it is created during installation.

The MsiShortCutProperty table is pretty new and I haven't really had any developers come to me wanting to leverage it yet so I haven't dug into the details of what all the various properties that can be set are.  However, I suspect this is the road you need to go down.

Comment: I am sorry I confused you. I should not have mentioned my initial problem of shortcuts. My question was if I set the integrity priority of the dlls that I need for the install build, will these settings persist on the machine that I install the program to? Or how can I check the integrity priority of the dll on the target-machine? I can run the program to see if it works properly, but since the original problem is intermitent, it would be very tedious.

Comment: So in googling, can you set the prioerity on dll's or is it only exe's?  I got the impression that it's a process thing although I don't really know the space at all.   The article you referenced an exe being updated.  I don't think it would persist across the install and that a custom action would have to be called to update the attribute.

Comment: I did set the IP on the dlls and move the dlls to the target-machine, then registered the dlls and ran the program. It seems to fix the original problem. Now I have to re-build the msi with the "new" dlls. I think the safest path is to redo the IP setting after the MSI install on the target-machine. I agree with you. Thanks.